# not able to select first child with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I have the following html element:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque.
            Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a
            nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada.
            Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus
            hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum
            tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>                                    
</div>
```

this element (`<div id='accordion'>`) clearly shows that it's first child is the h3 tag the next child is the div tag then the h3 etc

I want to select the fist child of this div. In other words I want to select the first h3 tag

as a result I have tried:

```
    $("#accordion:first-child").css("font-size","30px");
```

also

```
     $("#accordion:first").css("font-size","30px");
```

both ways applies a font of 30px to the main div element (`<div id='accordion'>`)

what am I doing wrong I want to only select the first child of the accordion it clearly is the h3 tag

### Edit

whow I was just missing a space. [this page](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) did not includes the pace.

I had to change my code from

```
$("#accordion:first").css("font-size","30px");
```

TO

```
$("#accordion :first").css("font-size","30px");
```

Comment: BTW `element:first-child` returns elements that are the first child of their parent.

Comment: @Tono My solution is faster: http://jsperf.com/first-vs-children

Comment: `whow I was just missing a space. this page did not includes the pace.` Yes, it did. The parent was the `div` and they were selecting the first child that was a span. Therefore their selector was `div span:first-child` they want the first span, with a ancestor of div.

Comment: @Chad ... with an *ancestor* of div, not parent. A space character is the descendant combinator!

Comment: @ŠimeVidas aparantly `.children().first()` is the fastest, by a very large margin: http://jsperf.com/first-vs-children/2

Comment: @Chad Yes, it's considerably faster. That's expected though, since `.children().first()` is roughly the same as `.children[0]`, whereas `.children( ':first' )` executes a selector check on each child. So, I recommend `.children().first()` or even `.children().eq( 0 )`...

Comment: The documentation failed me on this as well. They even have an example in the documentation which does not demonstrate the need for a space. They should consider updating that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to separate the id of the parent from the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector. Also, the frst-child selector will select all the first-child elements, not only one. To select only one you have to use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector.

```
$("#accordion h3:first").css("font-size","30px");
```

This is the way css selectors (which jQuery heavily uses) works.

Take a read at [css descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) here.

> At times, authors may want selectors to match an element that is the descendant of another element in the document tree (e.g., "Match
>   those EM elements that are contained by an H1 element"). Descendant
>   selectors express such a relationship in a pattern. **A descendant
>   selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by white
>   space**.

Also, according to the jQuery docs, there are better methods to retrieve the first child of an element, to achieve better performance.

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":first").

Comment: No, that's not it. This will select all descendants that are first-children... So, in this case it selects the H3, but also both A elements, and both P elements... **See for yourself:** http://jsfiddle.net/MxmTP/1/

Comment: @Sime right, was focusing on the importance of the space and didn't think about it, corrected using :first.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector, what you are looking for is:

```
$('#accordion h3:first-child').css('font-size', '30px');
```

From jQuery API Docs:

> ***Description**: Selects all elements that are the first child of their
>   parent.*

So the selector `#accordion:first-child` is the `#accordion` element that is the first child of its parent; while `#accordion h3:first-child` is an `h3` contained within `#accordion` that is the first child of *it's* parent.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
$( '#accordion' ).children( ':first' ).css( ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#accordion').children().first().css(...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":first", "#accordion").css("font-size", "30px")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a different between using jquery [first-selector](http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-first-selector) and  [first-child](http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-first-child-selector) selector.

Since you've multiple first-child elements you should use first selector only otherwise it can all first-child elements as @Jose mentiond.

```
$("#accordion h3:first").css("font-size","30px");

 OR


 $("#accordion h3:first").css("font-size","30px");
```

Either way it should work!